# Inverse images of general hyperplane sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose we have a proper birational map $f : X \to Y$ between projective varieties, where $X$ is smooth but $Y$ may not be.

If we take a general hyperplane section of $Y$, will its inverse image in $X$ be smooth?

Comment: In characteristic 0, this is the basepoint free Bertini Theorem which holds more generally for any morphism between projective varieties where the source is smooth. In characteristic p, this can fail if the field is finite (there may not be enough hyperplanes) and without imposing some extra conditions on the residue field extensions being separable. See this thread for a discussion of the latter issue: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67326/bertini-theorems-for-base-point-free-linear-systems-in-positive-characteristics.

Comment: @DoriBejleri Would you happne to know a reference for this basepoint-free Bertini theorem?

Comment: Corollary III.10.9 in Hartshorne.